# getting an immediate redirect. Why is this so?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am trying to redirect the user from one jsp page to another jsp page after making him wait for 10  seconds or 10000 milliseconds. But there is a redirect as soon as the page is opened in the browser. Why is this is so ? Is there anything wrong in the following code ? I am calling the `redirectFunction` which does the redirect.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP - 1</title>
    <script>
        function redirectFunction() {
            <% response.sendRedirect("jsp-2.jsp"); %>
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        Wait while you are redirected...
    </h1>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        setTimeout(redirectFunc,10000); // wait for 10 seconds,then call redirectFunc
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Make redirectFunction consistent... It is redirectFunc when you setting timeout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sends redirect exactly from server that`s why it fired immediatelly.

If you want to fire redirect after 10 seconds than you need to change your code:

```
function redirectFunction() {
    window.location.href = "jsp-2.jsp"
}
```

and `setTimeout(redirectFunction,10000);`

Actually when you call `<% response.sendRedirect("jsp-2.jsp"); %>` Java server sets http code 302 to your http response, and header Location: jsp-2.jsp
And browser redirects to page specified in Location header immediately.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but isn't it that the function `redirectFunction` should be called after 10 seconds ?

Comment: Yes but in your case, on browser it`s empty, cause there is no ServerCode inside it. Actually when you call <% response.sendRedirect("jsp-2.jsp"); %> Java server sets http code 302 to your http response, and header Location: jsp-2.jsp.

Comment: +1. What Alexey says is `response.sendRedirect` doesn't write some nice javascript that does the redirect on client. That method instruct the server to send `http status code 302` and `Location: <URL>` header to the client. Forgetting all the HTML content that you were about to send.

Comment: Then when browser gets that response, it redirects immediately to that page.

Comment: @Y.E.P you have to understand that what's inside `<% ... %>` executes when rendering the page. If what's inside is writing some output, ok, that output will be there and you will view it on your produced HTML. But `response.sendRedirect` is something like `tell the client to go somewhere else, and that's it.`.

Answer (score 1):

the code in scriptlet is executed on the server, it is not javascript. use this

```
function redirectFunction() {
            window.location.href = "jsp-2.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29), what's happening is that you're sending the HTTP location header with a  status code 302. This happens when the page is requested, not during client-side execution of the JavaScript.

If you want it to be during JavaScript execution you need to assign the URL you want to window.location.

```
window.location = "http://google.com";
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
 <script>
        function redirectFunction() {
            <% response.sendRedirect("jsp-2.jsp"); %>
        }
 </script>
```

is translated and executed as

```
out.print(" <script> function redirectFunction() {");
response.sendRedirect("jsp-2.jsp");
out.print("</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The call sendRedirect is executed on the server side, while preparing your page, and it's performing the redirect. You can do the sleep and the redirect in javascript only, using window.location.